# Play a video with jQuery located inside an iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, html5-video

I have an iFrame on a page set to `display: none;`

```
<div id="the-stage" style="display:none;">
<iframe src="index.html" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
</div><!--end the-stage-->
```

Which has a `<video>` tag within it:

```
<video id="video1" width="345" height="264" controls poster="poster.jpg">
<source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
<source src="video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
<source src="video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

On the page which has the `<iframe>` tag, I was trying to play the video when the hidden div is revealed:

```
jQuery("a.launch").click(function(){
jQuery("#the-stage").fadeIn();
jQuery("#video1").get(0).play();
return false;
});
```

But then I got the following error in the console:

> // The console output. cannot call method play of undefined

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `contents()` to get the iframe content and then find the `video` element. Also you should make sure to do this after the `div` is visible i.e when fading is complete. The reason is when the `div` which contains `iframe` is hidden the `video` will not play.

```
jQuery("a.launch").click(function(){
   jQuery("#the-stage").fadeIn(function(){
       jQuery("#the-stage").find("iframe").contents().find("#video1").get(0).play();
   });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the `document` of the `iframe` with [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

```
jQuery('#the-stage').contents().find('#video1').get(0).play();
```